# How can magic be harvested in Golarion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, lore, golarion

In the Inner Sea World Guide in the Mana Wastes section is written that the Calikang leave the desert to harvest magic. The reason is to set the magic free when returning to the Mana Wastes to the refill the empty magic vessle.

What concept of magic lies behind this? How can I harvest and store magic?

Comment: Hm... on one hand, this question is asking a specific question about a specific setting for which there might be a good answer. On the other hand, it's very theoretical and would fit well in [worldbuilding.se]. I'm not going to flag it as off-topic because it can fit, but I'm going to let you know that you could find some more insight over at [worldbuilding.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You currently can't harvest magic

I did look up on nearly every pdf i have and the only reference about them harvesting mana is on that entry, everything else talks about absorbing energy to health themselves, or how they are related to vudra deities (look for [AP #29](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8bc1?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-29-Mother-of-Flies) for a complete story, habitat and ecology articles, but most can be seen [here](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Calikang)). But no, nothing else that can answer this.

So (to me), this sounds like **flavor text that was never explored** due to limitations on the rules system. Instead, they got a mechanic that allows them to absorb energy damage and heal themselves.

Considering that both the original creature and the region were written back when 3.5 was the default system for Golarion, it is very likely that the authors had [Mana Crystals](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Mana_Crystal_(3.5e_Equipment)) in mind when writing those entries.

Otherwise, you will notice that *mana* isn't even defined by the rules system.

The closest thing to "harvesting" (storing for later use) are the [Spell Absorption](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spell-absorption/) spell, [pearls of power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power/), and the [Rod of Absorption](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-absorption/). [Noqual golems](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-noqual/) also seem to be able to absorb magic energy, since they are constructed from magic resistant [skymetal](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Skymetal).